# CloudFormation - user does not own network ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, acl, aws-cloudformation

Getting the error 'user XXXXXXXXX does not own a resource nvirgi-acl2-15txjsljshg15' (nvirgi-acl2-15txjsljshg15 is the name of the created acl), below is my cloud formation JSON for the vpc,subnets,acl and networkacl. How do i get pass this error ?

```
"VPC1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.10.0.0/16",
        "InstanceTenancy": "default",
        "EnableDnsSupport": "true",
        "EnableDnsHostnames": "false",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "My Dashboard"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "subnet1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.48.0/20",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }          
    },
    "subnet2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/20",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2b",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        },
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "MyDashboard"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "subnet3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.32.0/20",
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }
    },
 "acl1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "Egress": "true",
        "Protocol": "-1",
        "RuleAction": "allow",
        "RuleNumber": "100",
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "NetworkAcl1"
        }
      }
    },
    "acl2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "Protocol": "-1",
        "RuleAction": "allow",
        "RuleNumber": "101",
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "NetworkAcl2"
        }
      }
    },
    "acl3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "0.0.0.0/0",
        "Egress": "true",
        "Protocol": "-1",
        "RuleAction": "allow",
        "RuleNumber": "102",
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "NetworkAcl3"
        }
      }
    },  
    "subnetacl1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "acl1"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "subnet1"
        }
      }
    },
    "subnetacl2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "acl2"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "subnet2"
        }
      }
    },
    "subnetacl3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation",
      "Properties": {
        "NetworkAclId": {
          "Ref": "acl3"
        },
        "SubnetId": {
          "Ref": "subnet3"
        }
      }
    },
"NetworkAcl1": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }
    },
    "NetworkAcl2": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }
    },
    "NetworkAcl3": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {
          "Ref": "VPC1"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the [`NetworkAclId`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-subnet-network-acl-assoc.html#cfn-ec2-subnetnetworkaclassociation-networkaclid) property in the `AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation` resources (`"subnetacl[1-3]"`) must reference the `AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl` resources (`"NetworkAcl[1-3]"`), not the  `AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry` resources (`"acl[1-3]"`) as they are currently.

Comment: I have added the NetworkAcl's in the question. Not creating anything manually. The user has all the permissions required too

Comment: Updated my answer based on the additional info provided, hope this helps.